# How and why does NetworkManager during systemd boot create a connection in /run/NetworkManager/system-connections colliding with /etc/...?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Ubuntu 19.04, 5.0.0-32-generic x86_64.

My (geriatric, I know) onboard `atl1` ethernet chip is getting extremely hot, even temporarily fails (until reboot), when heavily networking at 1000 MB/s. Tried to reduce speed to 100 MB/s with both the nm- app and `nmcli` which worked and was saved to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-enp3s0.nmconnection` (amongst other files in there).

On next boot, the NIC is back to 1000 MB/s, obviously - according to `journalctl` - using `/run/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-enp3s0.nmconnection` and running into a conflict:

> keyfile: cannot load /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-enp3s0.nmconnection due to conflicting UUID for /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/netplan-enp3s0.nmconnection (6effa1b1-280b-3785-9b52-c723b445fb3e,"netplan-enp3s0")

The UUID of the two files is identical.

Other setting made and saved with `nmcli`, like IP4 address, are being adhered to and reused on reboot. Admittedly, those could come fron `netplan`. Unfortunately, NIC speed cannot be defined with `netplan`.

What is strange is I can't get rid of the connection in `/run/...`, even after deleting all files in `/etc/...` a (default?) connection in `/run/...` comes up on reboot and conflicts with the ones in `/etc/...` (if existent).

Searching the entire file system beyond `{run,etc,lib}` for default settings didn't give me any hints.

I think I've done my bit searching this and other sites, reading man pages and pertinent and similar articles, but I'm out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

The file in /run gets written during boot by netplan. I personally would disable netplan and configure the profile in NetworkManager directly.